# How do I set caching headers to cache the GET of a url, but not the POST of the url?

Tags: caching

How do I set caching headers to cache the GET of a url, but not the POST of the url?

For example, I have the url: `/user/register`. Doing a GET on that url returns the registration form.  Doing a POST on that url performs the registration.  I'd like the form to be cached since it doesn't change often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSTs don't get cached, as the entire intent of POST is to change something. Set whatever caching you like on the URL, they'll be ignored for the POST side of things.

Comment: POSTs are not SUPPOSED to get cached :) Some homegrown idiot cache might do it, but I agree with your post that it should be safe to rely on that